# I keep having to make a "push" div to prevent text overflowing

Tags: css, html, overflow, containers

I followed a tutorial on how to correctly contain text in a 100% percent height div container however after modifying the HTML and adding new CSS for my client's website, the text seemed to overflow out of the main content div container again. The only solution I found was to create a div tag like `<div style="height:1020px;"></div>` placed right after the overflowing text but before the ending `</div>` for the main content div container `<div id="container">` so that the main content div container would stretch down to contain the overflowing text.

The problem with my solution is that I have to set a different height level for the "push" tag with every page since each page has different length of text and I have to reduce the amount of white space under the text. I have tried `word-wrap: break-word` which didn't work. The text will overflow if you keep zooming in or you are already on a certain zoom level. I am testing this on Chrome.

Here is the Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eUHBX/1/

Comment: see here: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/expandingboxbug.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see there is an issue with your HTML. All of your content is within the header div which means the height is restricted to the height of the header. I have removed the height attributes in the content section of your CSS and changed the header height to 180px.

I have also corrected your HTML structure. Here is the working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hollandben/eUHBX/8/

Hope that helps